# how to find the process with dynamic name

Tags: c#, windows, process

C# Windows 10
So I'm searching for 2 hours and now I am done - have no idea how to do it.
I need to find the process that has dynamic name.
I mean this is not working:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc.ProcName);
```

It wont find the process, because its name dynamicly changes.
Finding processes by ID - no way, ID changes too.
Any ideas?

Comment: You need *something* to identify the process you want. It's like saying, "I'm looking for a book. I don't know the title, and I don't know the author. So how can I find it?"

Comment: forgot to say - the one thing that i see the same all the time - path to the .exe file.
But its very non-effective way to loop through the all processes and compare paths.

Comment: "ID changes too" - then it's _not_ the same process.

Comment: Of course it is. After i ll reboot my pc - code ll become junk because all the processes are different :D

Comment: If the only thing you have to identify the process is the path, then that's what you have to use. (Here's a secret: You know how GetProcessesByName works? [It loops through all the processes and compares names](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,1559).)

Comment: So is there a way to fastly loop through process list? I ve done it, but its very slowly - there is too much processes and exceptions of windows processes (too slow to catch them). Like if I need to find 5 processes with dynamic names - it ll be 5 time loop through the processes.

Comment: Is GetProcessesByName fast enough? You seemed to be okay with using it earlier, and it just loops through the process list.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that it uses GetProcesses() too. But anyway GetProcessesByName() works faster- I think because of exceptions. I have too much exceptions like System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. This makes it go slowly (i think)

Comment: I have no ideas how to avoid System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception , that Windows processes throws. Help me please(

Comment: I linked you to the source code for GetProcessByName(). You can just steal that code.